# Unable to select multiple options from autocomplete drop-down using selenium web-driver python

Tags: javascript, python, angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate a webpage written in Angular and i have auto-complete dropdown which have a lot of elements in it. I'm trying to click each element and check if it populates all the fields below.
Here is the innerHTML for that dropdown

```
<div class="mat-autocomplete-panel mat-autocomplete-visible" role="listbox" id="mat-autocomplete-0">
<!---->
<mat-option _ngcontent-c3="" class="mat-option" role="option" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-67" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
    <!---->
    <span class="mat-option-text">  Miss </span>
    <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
</mat-option>
<mat-option _ngcontent-c3="" class="mat-option" role="option" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-68" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
    <!---->
    <span class="mat-option-text">  SLCA </span>
    <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
    </mat-option>
<mat-option _ngcontent-c3="" class="mat-option mat-selected" role="option" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-21" aria-selected="true" aria-disabled="false">
```

I tried using select but it gives an error saying that the tag should be **select** not **div**. So is there way around this or do i have to switch another language(such as JS to write the automate the testing on angular). Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use following Code :**

**If Autocomplete drop-down get closed after selecting one of option :**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='mat-autocomplete-0']").click()

all_options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='mat-option-text']")
i = 0
while i<len(all_options) : 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='mat-autocomplete-0']").click()
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='mat-option-text']")[i].click()
    i=i+1
```

**If Autocomplete drop-down stays as it after selecting one of option :**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='mat-autocomplete-0']").click()    

all_options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='mat-option-text']")
i = 0
while i<len(all_options) : 
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='mat-option-text']")[i].click()
    i=i+1
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Hello, it gives me an **StaleElementReferenceException** and saying the element is not attached to the page document

Comment: @Girishvenkata : Does drop-down get closed on selection of option, If it stays open even after selection then no need of - driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='mat-autocomplete-0']").click() , so remove it and run the code

Comment: Yes the dropdown closes after we select an option and thank you your code does work.